# Joining two unrelated view-tables with nhibernate and ICriteria

Tags: c#, sql, .net, nhibernate, icriteria

I have two entities based on two views. The mappings looks like this:

**Entiy A:**

```
<class name="SearchView" table="SearchView" dynamic-update="true" mutable="false" schema-action="none">
    <id name="Id" type="Guid" column="Id" />
    <property name="Id" column="Id" type="Guid" />
    <property name="Expires" column="Expires" type="DateTime" />
    <property name="VerificationNumber" column="VerificationNumber" type="Int32" />
    <property name="InvoiceNo" column="InvoiceNo" type="Int32" length="50" />
    <property name="Status" column="FakturaStatus" type="Int32" />
</class>
```

**Entity B:**

```
<class name="SearchInvoiceResourceLookUpView" table="SearchInvoiceResourceLookUpView" dynamic-update="true" mutable="false" schema-action="none">
    <id name="Id" type="Guid" column="Id" />

    <property name="InvoiceId" column="InvoiceId" type="Guid" />
    <property name="ResourceId" column="ResourceId" type="Guid" />        
</class>
```

**Entity A** is based on a table view that is a flattened view of a more complex table-structure, for search optimization. Now i want to be able to get all the rows from **Entity A** where the Id is in column "InvoiceId" in **Entity B** for a specific value of "ResourceId" in **Entity B** by using NHibernate and the Criteria-API. The both tables are views and they have no declared relationship. I have tried the following code in C# but it doesn't work:

```
        var criteria = _session.CreateCriteria(typeof(SearchView));
            criteria.CreateAlias("SearchInvoiceResourceLookUpView", "srf",JoinType.InnerJoin)
                .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("sfr.InvoiceId", "Id"))
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("sfr.ResourceId", invoiceResId));
```

**The raw SQL for this purpose would be:**

```
SELECT * FROM SearchView
JOIN SearchInvoiceResourceLookUpView srf on srf.InvoiceId = Id 
WHERE srf.ResourceId = '[Inser resource id here]'
```

**How do i solve this?**

**Is there another, better way to do this?**

Answer (score 3):

In scenarios whithout explicit mapping between our entities, we can use **only** HQL.

- [14.2. The from clause](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-from) *(small cite and snippet)*

> Multiple classes may appear, resulting in a cartesian product or "cross" join.

```
from Formula, Parameter
from Formula as form, Parameter as param
```

So in the case above we would have HQL like this:

```
FROM SearchView AS sv, SearchInvoiceResourceLookUpView AS srf
WHERE srf.InvoiceId = sv.Id
AND srf.ResourceId = '[Inser resource id here]'
```

*Also some SELECT should be used and maybe DTO with Result Transformer...*

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I suppose that this can be done with Linq as well?

Comment: Cannot say about NHibernate's Linq provider... I would say it is now working with HQL, so maybe... but really not sure... ;( *My preference is Criteria or QueryOver or even HQL...*

Comment: I will try both. There is also a need to include or not include parameters in the query depending on what parameters are provided when searching.