# Nhibernate QueryOver JoinAlias UnRelated Entity

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an issue in NHibernate regarding a left join using "JoinAlias" when the result query SQL that I am looking for is this :

```
"select * from EntityA T1 left join EntityB T2 on T2.EntityAId=T1.id"
```

And in NHibernate I have this but doesn't work:

```
 var query = _session.QueryOver(() => EntityA)
                      .Left.JoinAlias(() => EntityA, () => EntityB.EntityA)
```

In NHibernate `EntityA` doesn't reference to `EntityB` but `EntityB` as a reference to `EntityA`.

```
public class EntityA
{ 
   public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class EntityB
{ 
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public EntityA EntityA {get;set;}
}
```

How can I make this very simple left join in HHibernate Work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with `Criteria` or `QueryOver`. But we can use **HQL**, which does support that

- [14.2. The from clause](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-from) *(small cite and snippet)*

> Multiple classes may appear, resulting in a cartesian product or "cross" join.

```
from Formula, Parameter
from Formula as form, Parameter as param
```

So in the case above we would have HQL like this:

```
FROM EntityA T1 
   , EntityB T2 
WHEERE T2.EntityAId = T1.id
```

*Almost the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26335220/1679310)*

But in case described above, there is reversed relation, already mapped. And that means, that we can extend the C# entity definitions:

```
public class EntityA
{ 
   public int Id {get;set;}
   // one-to-many
   // the bidirectional mapping of the below relation
   public IList<EntityB> EntityBColl { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{ 
   public int Id {get;set;}
   // many-to-one
   // this is the inversed end in fact of the bidirectional mapping
   public EntityA EntityA {get;set;}
}
```

Having that in place, we can use standard `QueryOver` API:

```
// aliases
EntityA EntityA = null;
EntityB EntityB = null;

// query
var query = session.QueryOver(() => EntityA)
    .Left.JoinAlias(() => EntityA.EntityBColl , () => EntityB)
    ...
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it then by adding the collection column to Entity .