# Mapping to Date part of Sql DateTime

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a requirement to be able to fetch data related to a particular Date as opposed to DateTime, for a particular colmumn.

Is it at all possible to Map the related objects according to an extracted date part of a date time? Where no explicit foreign key relationship exists between the two entities?

Relating it to SQL, I would like it to generate a query as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Transactions trans 
    INNER JOIN TransactionDetails details
       ON trans.DatePerformed = CAST(details.datetimedetails AS DATE)
```

Comment: Firstly, you should have an `ON` clause included on the join not an `AND`. Secondly is `DatePerformed ` a datetime or a date? can you show some sample rows and your desired output?

Comment: DatePerformed is Date, DateTimeDetails is DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go in case we need the skip the **mapped** **relationship** mapping *(when `CROSS JOIN` with `WHERE` clause is needed)* we can use **HQL** *(only way, check e.g. here:)*

- [How to join Two tables of two non relashinship defined columns using Nhibernate QueryOver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28689706/1679310)
- [Nhibernate QueryOver JoinAlias UnRelated Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26884917/1679310)

The HQL sytax then would be:

```
var hql = " SELECT trans " +
          " FROM TransactionEntity trans "
          "    , TransactionDetails details " + // CROSS JOIN without any ON
          " WHERE trans.DatePerformed = CAST(trans.datetimedetails as Date) " +
          "";

var query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
var results = query.List<TransactionEntity>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The way with `QueryOver` would be:

```
TransactionEntitytrans = null;
TransactionDetails details = null;

var results = session.QueryOver<TransactionEntity>(() => trans)
    .JoinQueryOver(() => trans.Details, () => details, JoinType.InnerJoin
        , Restrictions.EqProperty(
            Projections.Property<TransactionEntity>(_ => trans.DatePerformed ),
            Projections.Cast(
              NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.Date, 
              Projections.Property<Occupation>(_ => details.datetimedetails ))
            )
    )
    .List<TransactionEntity>();
```

What we are effectively doing is the usage of the forth parameter of the `.JoinQueryOver()`. This parameter is a restriction *(`ICriterion withClause`)* and is added to the JOIN with AND operator

```
INNER JOIN TransactionDetails details
   ON  trans.ID = details.TransactonID
   // here is injected the with clause
   AND trans.DatePerformed = CAST(details.datetimedetails AS DATE)
```

And in this withClause we are just creating restriction with a small trick **`Restrictions.EqProperty()`**, because this takes to projections

```
EqProperty(IProjection lshProjection, IProjection rshProjection)
```

*(so we do not compare two properties but some other projections)*. And then we just use CAST to get the required result

Comment: Thanks @Radim. Good detail in your explanation. I am trying it out now.

Comment: Hi @Radim, what about the actual NHibernate mappings? Are you saying I wont need them between the two entities?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Well I do not. If you are asking "should we define the JOIN explicitly" ... NO this will be done for us by NHibernate. it comes from relationship... it cannot be avoided... is it your question?

Comment: I realise, you were answering before I did an edit in the expected SQL statement. Sorry about that. I had mistakenly joined on Id as well. I meant to join on that date field. ...without a defined relationship on the existing data

Comment: OK, so your question is *"Can I query **two** entities, with my OWN custom JOIN clause?"* the answer is **NO** with `QueryOver` or `ICriteria`, - but yes with `HQL`. Please, check this explanation *(larger than comment;)* http://stackoverflow.com/q/28689706/1679310 or here http://stackoverflow.com/q/26884917/1679310, Also, the concept shown in this answer with HQL would be very similar ;)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Would you please include your last comment in your answer, so I mark it as an answer?

Comment: Had to add a bit more complex answer.. with all the HQL details ;) Good luck with amazing NHibernate ;) sir!