# NHibernate (+ FluentNhibernate) : Join two detached tables

Tags: join, nhibernate, subquery, queryover

'tI encounter problems to create a join on two entities with a common property but they are not map together.

Say you have an entity Article which contains a property FamilyCode and an entity Family with properties Code and Label.

In my mappings, Article doesn't reference Family and i don't want to change that (to keep compatibility with others internal and legacy methods).

So, i can't translate the below query in Nhibernate :

```
SELECT f.Code, f.Label
FROM Article a
INNER JOIN Family f ON a.FamilyCode = f.Code
WHERE f.Label LIKE 'p%'
```

I can't use JoinQuery because i can't inject a QueryOver and i don't konw if it's possible by using WithSubquery.

I tried to Future QueryOver and QueryOver and then perform a Join in memory (after .List() each) but i have too much rows for Article so it takes long time.

Do you have ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use HQL - but **only** HQL.

- [14.2. The from clause](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryhql.html#queryhql-from) *(small cite and snippet)*

> Multiple classes may appear, resulting in a cartesian product or "cross" join.

```
from Formula, Parameter
from Formula as form, Parameter as param
```

So that would be the way with HQL

```
SELECT f.Code, f.Label
FROM Article a,
     Family f 
WHERE a.FamilyCode = f.Code
AND f.Label LIKE 'p%'
```

Check also this [9.3.2. The IQuery interface](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-queryinterface) and maybe this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26335220/1679310)

Comment: Ok so i can't use QueryOver notation ? In fact, the basic problem is that i can't use the LIKE with Linq notation.

Comment: For queries like you need the answer is **no** you cannot use query over. just HQL. Every ORM is about mapped relations. This is it. NHibernate has a bonus (HQL) where we can break it. But not for any other queries...