# How to join Two tables of two non relashinship defined columns using Nhibernate QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Using NHibernate `QueryOver`, I want to join two tables using two columns which are not defined in the mapping as a relationship.

E.g. This is not my exact scenario but this can explain that

Tables:

```
Employee(Id, Name, DepartmentId, SomeCode,Address)

Department (Id, Name, ,Code)
```

Select

```
SELECT * 
  FROM EMPLOYEE E 
  JOIN DEPARTMENT D 
    ON D.Code = E.SomeCode
```

Can someone please tell me how to do this query using NHibernate `QueryOver`. Note that "SomeCode" in `Employee` and "Code" in `Department` are not defined as a relationship. DepartmentId is the foreign key and I can join these using `JoinAlias` but I want it in a somewhat different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are similar questions, e.g.

- [NHibernate (+ FluentNhibernate) : Join two detached tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27522520/1679310)
- [Hibernate Criteria Projection without mapped association of tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25679783/1679310)

And the answer is:

1. either use **HQL** and CROSS JOIN (with WHERE)
2. There is **NO** way how to do that with `QueryOver`/`Criteria`)

See the doc:

#### [14.2. The from clause](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-from)

> Multiple classes may appear, resulting in a cartesian product or "cross" join.

```
from Formula, Parameter

from Formula as form, Parameter as param
```

So using HQL in your case, we can do it like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM EMPLOYEE E, DEPARTMENT D 
WHERE D.Code = E.SomeCode
...
```

BUT I would suggest: create that mapping in the code. Simply introduce `many-to-one` relation. It will be loaded lazily (only if used) and will nicely serve to our needs - be used in `QueryOver` as a relation for `Join`

If there is such relation, if this exist in the business object domain, we should not be scared to use it. We can hide it via security etc...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am (new to NHibernate) not much aware of how we can introduce a relationship in code as you suggested. Is it possible give me some hint. Can we add that relationship at the place I want and then get rid of that (kind of temporary relationship).

Comment: Yes please, check the [5.1.10. many-to-one](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone). There is a mapping for references (employee department, driven by **`property-ref`**. Search for that, and that will give you the answer ;) Enjoy NHibernate