# Override join 'ON' primary column in Criteria

Tags: join, nhibernate, criteria, createcriteria

I am using Criteria and I want to explicitly tell hibernate to join on specific columns rather than the primary and foreign key columns. My code is

```
CreateCriteria<Application>("Application")
.CreateCriteria("Application.Address", "Address", JoinType.FullJoin)
```

The query that runs for this is

```
Select * from Application app Full Join Address add ON app.AdressId = add.Id
```

I want the query to be as

```
Select * from Application app Full Join Address add ON app.PersonId = add.PersonId
```

I changed my criteria to

```
CreateCriteria<Application>("Application")
.CreateCriteria("Application.Address", "Address", JoinType.FullJoin, Restrictions.eqProperty("Application.Person.Id", "Address.Person.Id"))
```

The sql query that runs is

```
Select * from Application app Full Join Address add ON app.PersonId = add.PersonId and app.AdressId = add.Id
```

Is there a way I can explicitly mention in the criteria on the joins I wish to have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate always does joins basing on foreign keys. 
I guess that you have configured relationship between `Application` and `Address` entities via `Application.AddressId` foreign key. 
That's why you have `app.AdressId = add.Id` in join.

If I'm right you cannot do the join on some other property. 
You can find a slower workaround with subqueries or write a sql query manually.

See other answers:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28689750/5126411
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44924773/5126411